# How to set {0} (this is used in messages_en.utf8) value in install4j?

Tags: install4j

My istall4j build application contains the wrong name for .exe installation file ? On further investigation I found that it is substituting {0} while building the installer. In messages_en.utf8 file the tittle is setted as: SetupWindowTitle=Setup - {0}
From where does the value of {0} is took ? And how can I update the value of {0} with some new value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{0} is replaced with the application name and the version number that were entered on the "General settings->Application info" step.

To change that message, go to the "General settings->Languages" step, set up a custom localization file and override the message "SetupWindowTitle" with your own message.